# add CSS to the parent element

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following HTML example code:

```
<div>
    <span class="foo">
</div>

<div>
    <span class="moo">
</div>
```

I want to add some CSS styles to the div that contains a child with `moo` class.
Can I add a style to an element, when containing a specific child, with CSS only ?

Comment: No, you can't do it, there is not parent selector in css.

Comment: You can use `jQuery` for this. https://api.jquery.com/parent/

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't select parent in pure css. you will have to add a class to your parent div

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 $(".moo").parent().css("...","...")
```

There is no pure CSS solution. U have to resort to jquery or jscript

Comment: Not the downvoter, but the question says "*by CSS only*"